# How I can use InvoiceShipment Delegate PXOverride in ShipmentEntry acumatica

Tags: delegates, acumatica

I was implemented a delegate process of InvoiceShipment to validate the updated inventory after creating an invoice,  in version 6.1 of acumatica, but in version 18.117.0016 the method isn't executed

I tried in two different forms, but the method isn't executed

1.

```
public delegate void InvoiceShipmentDelegate(SOInvoiceEntry docgraph, SOShipment shiporder, DateTime invoiceDate, DocumentList<ARInvoice, SOInvoice> list);
        [PXOverride]
        public void InvoiceShipment(SOInvoiceEntry docgraph, SOShipment shiporder, DateTime invoiceDate, DocumentList<ARInvoice, SOInvoice> list, InvoiceShipmentDelegate baseMethod)
        {
            SOOrderShipment envio = PXSelect<SOOrderShipment, Where<SOOrderShipment.shipmentNbr, Equal<Required<SOOrderShipment.shipmentNbr>>>>.Select(Base, shiporder.ShipmentNbr);

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(envio.InvtRefNbr))
            {
                throw new PXException("No se puede preparar la factura, el inventario no ha sido actualizado");
            }

            baseMethod?.Invoke(docgraph, shiporder, invoiceDate, list);

        }
```

2.

```
public void InvoiceShipment(SOInvoiceEntry docgraph, SOShipment shiporder, DateTime invoiceDate, DocumentList<ARInvoice, SOInvoice> list, 
                                 Action<SOInvoiceEntry, SOShipment, DateTime, DocumentList<ARInvoice, SOInvoice>> baseInvoiceShipment)
        {
            SOOrderShipment envio = PXSelect<SOOrderShipment, Where<SOOrderShipment.shipmentNbr, Equal<Required<SOOrderShipment.shipmentNbr>>>>.Select(Base, shiporder.ShipmentNbr);
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(envio.InvtRefNbr))
            {
                throw new PXException("No se puede preparar la factura, el inventario no ha sido actualizado");
            }
            baseInvoiceShipment(docgraph, shiporder, invoiceDate, list);

    }
```

How I can Execute this delegate method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the signature of that method changed (added `PXQuickProcess.ActionFlow`). Because you are overriding the old unused signature it does not get called. Use this signature and it should call into your override:

```
public virtual void InvoiceShipment(SOInvoiceEntry docgraph, SOShipment shiporder, DateTime invoiceDate, DocumentList<ARInvoice, SOInvoice> list, PXQuickProcess.ActionFlow quickProcessFlow)
{ //... }
```

You can look at the `SOShipmentEntry` source code for any reference to InvoiceShipment to see this change. I am looking at 18.120.0006 for this example.

Comment: Thanks, I redolved de problem with PXQuickProcess.ActionFlow quickProcessFlow

Comment: That is good to hear. If this resolved your question please close it by marking it as the answer